# Objective-C - where to put the NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have an NSNotificationCenter selector,

where to put it ? in the delegate (if yes then where?) in the controller?

where to put the method as well.

do i need to dealloc the NSNotificationCenter ?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceNotificationReceived:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];



- (void)deviceNotificationReceived:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.soundMgr endInterruption];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `deviceNotificationReceived:` method must be an instance method of the argument to `addObserver:`. It is `self` in this instance, so your method should go in the same class.

You should not release the NotificationCenter, as you did not create or retain it.

Your question was a little hard to understand, is this what you were asking?

Comment: ok. so if i need that that my ViewController will get that notification for example after a call entered and abandoned and the app return the app need to call this method, where will i put the NSNotificationCenter to call the method?

Comment: you should probably put the call inside the `initWithNibName:bundle:` if you need it inside your ViewController.

Comment: Since this is an iPhone application, I think viewDidLoad: might be a better place for it, and then unregister in the viewDidUnload:. Normally you only want a view to respond to the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification only if it was the active view at the time of the interruption

Comment: @bodnarbm that's probably better if it's a root view controller; it could cause some issues if the view is lazy loaded.

Answer (score 2):

> Hi, i have an NSNotificationCenter selector,

okay, you mean you have a selector for a method in NSNotificationCenter.

> In Objective-C, “selector” has two
>   meanings. It can be used to refer
>   simply to the name of a method when
>   it’s used in a source-code message to
>   an object. It also, though, refers to
>   the unique identifier that replaces
>   the name when the source code is
>   compiled.
>   [http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/....../ocSelectors.html](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocSelectors.html)

So you have created a selector that refer to a method.

> where to put it ?

It's a variable, you can store it where ever you feel it fits in your design.

> in the delegate

See above.

> (if yes then where?)

It's a variable, it depends on your usage.

> in the controller?

Do you have controller? Depends on your design.

> where to put the method as well.

Which method?

> do i need to dealloc the NSNotificationCenter ?

No, `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` returns a reference to the notification center, you don't dealloc it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are subscribing to the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification, the most logical place to put the notification is in the `applicationdDidFinishLaunching` method of your app delegate.

That's the first point your code gets called, so you cannot set it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

where to put it ?

It depend on when you need to register for notification. One way is to add observer in 'init' method of the class and remove notification in 'dealloc'method of the class.